# WhatsApp Business API - How to access a wacore container to Check-Health with Postman

Tags: docker, facebook, docker-compose, whatsapp, whatsapi

After proceed with the installation of WhatsApp Business API (developer single instance) in docker on windows 10 Enterprise, I´m facing the following msg error when using https://192.168.43.200:8080/v1/health by postman
Error msg:
{
"meta": {
"version": "v2.33.3",
"api_status": "stable"
},
"errors": [
{
"code": 1014,
"title": "Internal error",
"details": "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. Please check if wacore is running: wacore:6252"
}
]
}

Looking in log files it´s seems that the core is listening in one port that is different from expected by web

---> Web log
[2021-02-24 12:46:38.560338] app.INFO: [064af96616514f6f8b41fc530047db4b] Matched route "{route}". {"route":"GET_v1_health","route_parameters":{"_controller":"WhatsApp\Controller\HealthController::getHealth","_route":"GET_v1_health"},"request_uri":"https://192.168.43.200:8080/v1/health","method":"GET"} []

[2021-02-24 12:46:38.587929] app.INFO: [064af96616514f6f8b41fc530047db4b] Guard authentication successful! {"token":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken: PostAuthenticationGuardToken(user="admin", authenticated=true, roles="ROLE_ADMIN"))","authenticator":"WhatsApp\Security\TokenAuthenticator"} []

[2021-02-24 12:47:14.646964] app.INFO: [064af96616514f6f8b41fc530047db4b] Response: {"meta":{"version":"v2.33.3","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1014,"title":"Internal error","details":"php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. Please check if wacore is running: wacore:6252"}]} []

[2021-02-24 12:47:14.650236] app.INFO: [064af96616514f6f8b41fc530047db4b] Request GET_/v1/health returns 500 in 36269.15 ms [] []

===================================================================================
Core log
D 2021-02-24 12:10:39.282 UTC 28 apiendpointmanager.cpp:190] Endpoint "healthcheck" is listening on address "0.0.0.0" port 6253 req_id=Main
D 2021-02-24 12:10:39.282 UTC 29 apiendpointmanager.cpp:190] Endpoint "control" is listening on address "0.0.0.0" port 6252 req_id=Main

===================================================================================

- No one change was executed in docker-compose.yml. Is the same that is on GitHub (https://github.com/WhatsApp/WhatsApp-Business-API-Setup-Scripts) except network mode was changed "bridge" to "nat" since I´m using windows

$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
9d811d5d3283   Default Switch   ics       local
27dc22b69113   nat              nat       local
4e2733cd792d   none             null      local

$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                              PORTS                                          NAMES
8d7000856b95   docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.33.3       "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   17 hours ago   Exited (4294967295) 6 minutes ago                                                  postgres_waweb_1
909781cdb775   docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.33.3   "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   17 hours ago   Up 5 minutes                        6250-6253/tcp                                  postgres_wacore_1
7d68b7a61cad   postgres:10.6                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 hours ago   Up 6 minutes                        5432/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33060->3306/tcp   postgres_db_1
219b1e393f21   nginx                                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   42 hours ago   Exited (4294967295) 41 hours ago                                                   nostalgic_jennings

- The current WA_API_VERSION is 2.33.3
- Database used is Postgress10.6
- Looking at a similar question answered by @WeiyanWang ([How to access wacore container using WhatsApp Business API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874813/how-to-access-wacore-container-using-whatsapp-business-api/51890710#51890710)) I tried to execute the same command in Postgres, but no success

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

after some investigation on scenery described, I found some settings mistakes in windows docker.
To fix these problems following the steps:

1. Change docker settings to original installation
2. Choose the option "Switch to linux container..."
3. Reinstall the WhatsApp Business Api following documentation

Note: Is not necessary change the "bridge" to "nat" network settings. I just only changed the "waweb" from 9090:443 to 8080:443